# Flutter Network image are( null , argument type String?, const) Error

Tags: android, flutter, image, dart, drawer

Please help i dont know what i did wrong.

I did declare Final userr .

```
final userr = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

then

```
accountEmail:  Text(userr.displayName),
backgroundImage:  NetworkImage(userr.photoURL!)
```

both of them has the same error

[image: here is the error caption]

I did try removing all the const in the same page and nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

I Think,

`userr.photoURL!` may be `null` and `NetworkImage` expect `url` as `string` not `null`.

So, change type of `photoURL` to `String` from `String?`

Comment: can you please explain more , because photoURL is built in keyword how could i change it to string?

Comment: Oh,  so just check before passing into `NetworkImage` is null or not, then if null then pass some static image url to the `NetworkImage`.   Like: 
 `NetworkImage(userr.photoURL == null ? "some static url" : userr.photoURL)`